# Error Attribute "switchMinWidth" has already been defined when use module in project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I faced error that use module in project 
the custom module  build.gradle (Module:comibdtddatepickerlib)  have dependency  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+" that also in main project buid.gradle  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+"

but i exclude when i add dependency of module but still it give error

- Error:(253) Attribute "switchMinWidth" has already been defined
- Error:(253) Attribute "switchPadding" has already been defined
- Error:(254) Attribute "switchStyle" has already been defined
- D:\aaa\Doctors1\doctors\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml

when i import eclipse project in android studio

I have following gradle files

- build.gradle (Project:mainproject)
- build.gradle (Module:comibdtddatepickerlib)
- build.gradle (Module:datetimepickerlibrary)
- build.gradle (Module:mainproject)
- build.gradle (Module:libraryviewpagerindicator)
- build.gradle (Module:pagerSlidingTabStrip)
- build.gradle (Module:stickeyHeaderListView)
- build.gradle (Module:twoWayHorizontalScrollView)

coding for file is **build.gradle (Module: comibdtddatepickerlib)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    aaptOptions
            {
                cruncherEnabled = false
            }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+"
}
```

coding for file is **build.gradle (Module:datetimepickerlibrary)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
    }

    aaptOptions
    {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids.jar')
}
```

coding for file is **build.gradle (Module: mainproject)**  (Main Project)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    aaptOptions
    {
       cruncherEnabled = false
    }

    buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':stickeyHeaderListView')
    compile project(':twoWayHorizontalScrollView')
    compile(project(':libraryviewpagerindicator')){
        exclude group:'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile(project(':pagerSlidingTabStrip')){
        exclude group:'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile(project(':datetimepickerlibrary')){
        exclude group:'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile(project(':comibdtddatepickerlib')){
        exclude group:'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+"
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/glide-3.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/library-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-2-4.jar')
    compile files('libs/PdfViewer.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.3.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/sc-light-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/scpkix-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/scprov-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
}
```